# API error when trying to access IBM Quantum Computer using IBMQ API Token

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I'm trying to write a code so that if the token exists then it loads the account or else it asks the user for the API token. Below is the code for reference:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
try:
    IBMQ.load_account()
except Exception as e:
    api_key = input("Enter IBMQ API Key")
    IBMQ.save_account(api_key, overwrite=True)
    IBMQ.load_account()
```

However, even after using the exception handling, still getting below errors:

```
RequestsApiError: '401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/users/loginWithToken. Login failed., Error code: 3446.'
```

```
IBMQAccountCredentialsInvalidToken: 'Invalid IBM Quantum Experience token found: "" of type <class \'str\'>.'
```

Any work around this to resolve this issue?

Comment: You are not handling the exception for after the token you input is invalid. Enter the valid token and this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is slight different:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ

api_key = None
for attempt in range(3):                                                # <- (1)
    try:                                                                # <- (3)
        if api_key:
            IBMQ.save_account(api_key, overwrite=True)
        else:
            IBMQ.load_account()
        break                                                           # <- (4)
    except Exception:
        api_key = input("Enter IBMQ API Key (attempt %s): " % attempt)  # <- (2)
```

This 3-time-loop (line `(1)`, you can replace it for `while True:` if you prefer infinite looping over this) sets a variable `api_key` (line `(2)`) continuously asking for the key while *something* goes wrong (line `(3)`). The things that can go wrong are `save_account` and `load_account`. If nothing goes wrong (line `(4)`), then get out of the loop.